# Price Range Slider in jQuery & PHP with MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have used jquery price range slider. I want to filter out result using the jquery price range slider on same page. But this jquery price range slider is not working or variable of that value is not posted on same page.
  I have tried following code,

```
    <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['amount1'])) 
        { 
          echo $_SESSION['amount1'] = $_POST['amount1']; 
        } 
        if(isset($_POST['amount2'])) 
        { 
          echo $_SESSION['amount2'] = $_POST['amount2']; 
        } 
        if(isset($_POST['submit_range'])) 
        { 
            $sql = mysql_query("select * from hall_search_data_1 where rent BETWEEN '".$_SESSION['amount1']."' AND '".$_SESSION['amount2']."'"); 
            $res = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error()); 
        }    
    ?>
```

```js
 $(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 50000,
      values: [ 100, 1000 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).html( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        $( "#amount1" ).val(ui.values[ 0 ]);
        $( "#amount2" ).val(ui.values[ 1 ]);
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).html( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
     " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  });
```

```html
<div class="slider"> 
  <div id="slider-range"></div>

  <form method="get">
    <input type="hidden" id="amount1">
    <input type="hidden" id="amount2">
    <input type="submit" name="submit_range" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div> 

<!--here php code ---->

if(isset($_POST['amount1']))
{
echo $_SESSION['amount1'] = $_POST['amount1'];
}

if(isset($_POST['amount2']))
{
echo $_SESSION['amount2'] = $_POST['amount2'];
}

if(isset($_POST['submit_range']))
{


                            $sql = mysql_query("select * from hall_search_data_1 where rent BETWEEN '".$_SESSION['amount1']."' AND '".$_SESSION['amount2']."'");
                            $res = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
                        }
```

So please help me.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nkjqr/12/

Comment: What is your specific error? Additionally, please consider using the newer `mysqli_` functions as the old ones are deprecated.

Comment: @Jan When i used post method on form then giving this error,  Undefined index: amount1,amount2

Comment: @A.P. I like But i want with php & mysql on same page

Comment: @Dnyan Please clean the different code parts. Is this a `PHP` error you are getting? What is your form action? The `$_POST` array is not set until you have a form sending to it.

Comment: @Jan I want this result on same page trhats why i am not written any action

Comment: I wouldn't filter them with more MySQL statements. Just load them all as a JSON and then filter them on the front end to save additional undeed requests and more code.

Comment: @A.P. I want to show selected price after page refresh.

Comment: @A.P.  where should I print these session value.?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="slider"> 
  <div id="slider-range"></div>

  <form method="get">
    <input type="hidden" id="amount1">
    <input type="hidden" id="amount2">
    <input type="submit" name="submit_range" value="Submit">
   </form>
</div>
```

In your form you have missed `name` attribute, hence you are getting

> Undefined index: amount1,amount2

above error.

Update your code as follow

```
<form method="get">
  <input type="hidden" id="amount1" name="amount1">
  <input type="hidden" id="amount2" name="amount2">
  <input type="submit" name="submit_range" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: thank Its working but i want show minimum & maximum selected value at slider

Comment: If you want to show selected price after page refresh...., you can temporary    store that in session.

Comment: where should I print these session value.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94397/discussion-between-dnyan-and-a-p).